# Spell checking reStructuredText

Tags: linux, command-line, spell-check, aspell, restructuredtext

I'm writing and correcting API documentation in [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) using [reStructuredText](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/rst.html). Does anyone know of a good spellchecker that will handle this format, or a bunch of Unix/Linux tools that will allow me to use Aspell with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Sphinx extension for spell checking.  It uses `enchant`, rather than `aspell`, but perhaps you might find it useful.

https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/spelling

(formerly https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/sphinxcontrib-spelling)

there's a blog article about it here:

https://doughellmann.com/blog/2011/05/26/creating-a-spelling-checker-for-restructuredtext-documents/

which explains how the extension was created, so if you're set on/stuck with using aspell specifically, maybe you can adapt it to aspell.

Comment: This can only be used for sphinx projects, not for standalone rST files.

Answer (score 1):

Since `aspell` has options for checking `HTML` and `TeX` files, you can spell-check some `HTML` or `Tex` produced by `Sphinx`. I imagine you could also use `aspell` on text output from `Sphinx` - assuming that removes any mark-up (e.g. asterisks) that might confuse `aspell` .

Comment: What would the command line be for checking a single file interactively?

Comment: `aspell check [options] filename` according to the [manual](http://aspell.net/man-html/Spellchecking-Individual-Files.html#Spellchecking-Individual-Files)

Comment: I meant the Sphinx command. I can only find the command for building an entire directory full of files, rather than turning a single file into flat text.

Comment: I need to install `aspell-en` (archlinux) to fix the error `Error: No word lists can be found for the language "en_US".` On other package managers it is listed as `en-aspell`.

Comment: I'm not attached to any particular checker. I tried aspell. When I ran it with right-click "Send To" it created a zero-length file with the extension ".new," although the input contained many proprietary terms it couldn't have recognized. When I ran it from the command line I found that the installer didn't add it to the system path; when I got around that it gave the error "No word lists can be found." /// Apparently some hacking is needed to raise it to the "kick it and it moves" level. I'll investigate further when I have time, but my expectations are low; so far it gets an "F" for finish.

Comment: I tried the Sphinx spelling extension too, but I couldn't get Sphinx to recognize that it was there. Apparently the theme I'm using has its own virtual environment, and I have to install it in that environment. I asked for assistance, but the person I asked is pushing back instead, with "You shouldn't want to do that." This may or may not be a productive approach, but it's proving to be a difficult one.